# How to evaluate $\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} \, dx$ using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I am pretty sure that my answer is correct but given answer for the exercise from textbook Calculus James Steward was slightly different. Any idea to solve this:

$$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} \, dx$$

The given answers: $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x+\frac{1}{2})+c$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always remember that there is a standard technique in algebra for reducing a problem involving a quadratic polynomial (such as $x^2+x+1$) with a first-degree term to a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with no first-degree term.  The name of the technique is a three-word phrase that you've heard.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2+x+1 = \left ( x+\frac12 \right )^2+\frac{3}{4} $$

$$\begin{align} \int dx \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} &=  \int dx \frac{x+\frac12}{\sqrt{\left ( x+\frac12 \right )^2+\frac{3}{4}}}-\frac12 \int dx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left ( x+\frac12 \right )^2+\frac{3}{4}}}\end{align}$$

Comment: why we have to split off the $x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$? Is it wrong if we solve directly and obtained answer $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}sec\theta-\frac{1}{2}ln|sec\theta+tan\theta|+c$?

Answer (score 1):

First split off the bit that does not need a trigonometric substitution:
$$\int\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}=\int\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx
  -\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}\ .$$
You should see that the first integral is now easy.  For the second, complete the square:
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}}\ .$$
If you really want to use a trig substitution, try
$$x+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\tan\theta\ ,$$
which still leaves you with a slightly tricky integral.  Better, use the hyperbolic substitution
$$x+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sinh\theta\ .$$
If you want to directly get the answer from the book, do some algebra:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}
  =\frac{\displaystyle\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x+\frac{1}{2}}\ .$$
With a bit of thought you will see why this is easy to integrate.